# Casting List<MyObject> to IEnumerable<MyInterface>

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable

I'm still learning some of this c# stuff, and I couldn't find an answer to this question. Assuming that I have a list of MyObject implementing MyInterface

```
public class MyObject : IMyInterface { ...}

public List<MyObject> MyObjectList;
```

How can I return an `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>` with the contents of MyObjectList?

I mean, right now I have this:

```
List<IMyInterface> temp = new List<IMyInterface>();
foreach (MyObject obj in MyObjects) temp.Add(obj);
return (IEnumerable<IMyInterface>)temp;
```

But is it necessary to create a new list like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not create the original list as: public List<IMyInterface> MyObjectList; Then you can populate it with any object that implements that interface. For me, that would be the normal approach and why I'd define an interface in this manner. What's the objective of your code, that may help and might even reveal that an interface isn't the answer you are looking for.

Comment: FYI, this conversion will be legal in C# 4.  See my archive of notes on the design of this C# 4 feature if this topic interests you: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx

Comment: If I create a List<IMyInterface> there's some binding properties that won't be picked up by XAML when ItemsSource to the list

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify, I don't understand "picked up by XAML", do you mean "picked up by WPF"?

Comment: Yes, I meant WPF, but I might be wrong, I think I just found another reason why it wasn't picking up the binding ... So I think you might be right, declaring a List<IMyInterface> might solve all issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5, the easiest way to do this is:

```
return MyObjects.Cast<IMyInterface>();
```

You don't need to create a copy of everything - but until C# 4 comes out with its generic interface variance, you're stuck doing *something* like this.

If you're still using .NET 2.0, you can easily do something similar:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SafeCast<TSource, TResult>
    (IEnumerable<TSource> source) where TResult : TSource
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

(Note that this doesn't check for `source` being null; to do that properly you'd want two methods due to the deferred execution of iterator blocks.)

Then use:

```
return SafeCast<MyObject, IMyInterface>(MyObjects);
```

You *could* make it more like the LINQ version, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SafeCast<T>(IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

return SafeCast<IMyInterface>(MyObjects);
```

This has compile-time safety though - it wouldn't stop you from trying to convert a `List<string>` into an `IEnumerable<Guid>` for example.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon, that made concepts more clear for me!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [LINQ Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method works well here, something like MyObjects.Cast()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 3 and .NET 3.5 (or above), then you can use the LINQ suggestion that Jake presented:

```
return MyObjectList.Cast<IMyInterface>();
```

(There's no need for `AsEnumerable` in this particular circumstance)

However, if you're using a prior version (2.0 of C# and .NET or above), you can still use an iterator block:

```
foreach(MyObject obj in MyObjectList) yield return (IMyInterface)obj;
```